# Epoch time conversion in GNU bash, version 4.3.*

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How to convert any given time to its corresponding Epoch time in bash.

Bash Version:
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (powerpc-ibm-aix5.1.0.0)

I tried the following command but its not working
date -d "$DATE" '+%s'

```
Output:
date: Not a recognized flag: d
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]
```

Comment: please add $DATE, and what you receive. It worked for me. `date +"%s" -d '2015-12-24 10:11:15'
1450939275
`

Comment: What means "its not working" exactly?

Comment: Apparently you don't have Gnu date; that has nothing to do with your bash version. `man date` will likely tell you how to use the `date` installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your `Perl` interpreter is better than your `date` executable...

```
perl -MPOSIX::strptime -MPOSIX -e 'print mktime(POSIX::strptime("2015-12-26 13:05:01","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))'
1451135101
```

Or, maybe your `PHP` interpreter is happier than your `date` executable and your `Perl` interpreter:

```
php -r 'date_default_timezone_set("UTC");echo strtotime("2015-12-26 13:05:01");'
1451135101
```

Comment: Nope it is also not working for me.Getting this error:                        Can't locate POSIX/strptime.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.8.8/                                                                                        aix-thread-multi /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.8.8 /usr/opt/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.8.8/aix                                                                                        -thread-multi /usr/opt/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/opt/perl5/lib/site_perl .)

Comment: Normally you install missing modules from CPAN.